# Efficient way to fetch/update X records in a loop

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, application-design, queue

What I need is a simple process that handles requests.
I have setup a simple table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Requests (  
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
  request_param VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,  
  status ENUM ('requested', 'done', 'failed'),  
  when TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  finished TIMESTAMP NULL  
);
```

What I am doing is something like:
`SELECT * FROM Requests where status = 'requested' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1`

This way I pick up each request one at a time.
Then I do `UPDATE Requests set status='done', finished=NOW() where id = 123;`
(the id=123 assume it is from the SELECT request).
This works but I am not sure if this is another approach.
What would be better? E.g. doing a LIMIT 100? My concern is that the order by is not a good idea as the data grow. Does it make an impact if I always process e.g. per 100? I still have to order by right?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a queue of sorts.  You might want to look at something like RabbitMQ

Comment: @atxdba:You are almost right.Issue is that these kind of queues you are suggesting do not offer reliability

Comment: @atxdba:Also this is too simple to use a third party queue and not just a simple table (IMHO)

Comment: @atxdba:Reliability in the sense that items in the queue are not guaranteed to be lost

Comment: Previous comments are nonsense because they haven't actually asked you if the order everything is processed in matters. Also, rename `when`, it's a reserved word. You know your data - does it need processing in order?

Comment: @GrumpyPhil:Not really.I added the order by in the sense that if anyone tries to review the status is able to understand what has been processed so far.But the order does not really affect the results